# PHP mail() function returns 1 but no mail is sent despite configuring XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, smtp, yahoo-mail

In a PHP application during the sign up step, I'm sending an email with a verfication link to the user. I'm using XAMPP in localhost to serve the page, and my database is in another device but in the same network. When I fill the form and hit the sign up button, I get a success message, the database is updated but no email is received to my address. I've searched for answers and found out that I had to configure `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` properly in order for it work and I did that as well but still no mail is send. Can anyone explain why is this happening? Below are the configurations of both `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` as there is no problem with my signup.php since the database is updating.

**sendmail.ini**

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server= smtp.mail.yahoo.com

smtp_port=465

smtp_ssl=ssl

;default_domain=mydomain.com

error_logfile=error.log

;debug_logfile=debug.log

auth_username=mymail@yahoo.com

auth_password=mypassword

pop3_server=

pop3_username=

pop3_password=

force_sender=mymail@yahoo.com

force_recipient=

hostname=
```

**php.ini**

```
[mail function]
SMTP= smtp.mail.yahoo.com

smtp_port=465

sendmail_from = mymail@yahoo.com

sendmail_path = "\"C:\Users\GMKRG\Desktop\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe" -t"

;mail.force_extra_parameters =

mail.add_x_header=Off

mail.log = "\"C:\Users\GMKRG\Desktop\xampp\sendmail\error.txt"

;mail.log = syslog
```

I've also configured my yahoo account to accept mails from less secure apps but still no mail received. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
**Below is the php mail function in case it helps more.**

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $mailString);
$emailBody = "Please click on the link below to activate your account:\n\n";

$emailBody .= "localhost/website/activate.php?email=" . urlencode($email) . "&key=$activationKey";

if(mail($email, 'Confirm your registration', $emailBody, 'From:'.'myaddress@yahoo.com')){

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank you for registering. A 
           confirmation email has been sent to $email. Please click on the 
           activation link inside it to activate your account.</div>";
}
```

Comment: Your `sendmail_path` value looks a bit strange and is a Unix-only parameter. Your `mail.log` parameter value should just be `"C:\Users\GMKRG\Desktop\xampp\sendmail\error.txt"`

Comment: I finished trying your suggestion but nothing, I'm getting errors instead of a success message. That means the message was never sent in contrast to the initial state where the message was sent but not picked by the smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that yahoo smtp sever is not working properly with xampp. Once I switched to gmail everything worked.